# Reorder users in django auth

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a model that has a ForeignKey to the built-in user model in `django.contrib.auth` and I'm frustrated by the fact the select box in the admin always sorts by the user's primary key.

I'd much rather have it sort by username alphabetically, and while it's my instinct not to want to fiddle with the innards of Django, I can't seem to find a simpler way to reorder the users.

The most straightforward way I can think of would be to dip into my Django install and add

```
ordering = ('username',)
```

to the Meta class of the User model.

Is there some kind of monkeypatching that I could do or any other less invasive way to modify the ordering of the User model?

Alternatively, can anyone thing of anything that could break by making this change?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There is a way using [ModelAdmin objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) to specify your own form. By specifying your own form, you have complete control over the form's composition and validation.

Say that the model which has an FK to `User` is `Foo`.

Your `myapp/models.py` might look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Foo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    some_val = models.IntegerField()
```

You would then create a `myapp/admin.py` file containing something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin

class FooAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.order_by('username'))

    class Meta:
        model = Foo

 class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     form = FooAdminForm

 admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

Once you've done this, the `<select>` dropdown will order the user objects according to username. No need to worry about to other fields on `Foo`... you only need to specify the overrides in your `FooAdminForm` class. Unfortunately, you'll need to provide this custom form definition for every model having an FK to User that you wish to present in the admin site.

Comment: The ordering works great, but now those fields are coming up as required.  How can I keep them optional?

Answer (score 15):

Jarret's answer above should actually read:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from yourapp.models import Foo

class FooAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwds):
        super(FooAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwds)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = User.objects.order_by(...)

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # other stuff here
    form = FooAdminForm

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

so the queryset gets re-evaluated each time you create the form, as opposed to once, when the module containing the form is imported.

Comment: This looks like a far better answer that will automatically create all the fields required beyond just the User field.