# How do I specify an order of values in drop-down list in a Django ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

OK, here is the question.

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):   

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('team',  'related_projects')
```

In `models.py` the `User` class is defined as follows:

```
class User (models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, verbose_name = _('team'))
    related_projects = models.ManyToManyField(Project, blank = True)
```

Both `team` and `related_projects` are rendered as a dropdown-box. The values are all the existing teams in the system, and all the existing projects in the system. That's all right, but they're only ordered by primary key, and I would like to see them ordered alphabetically.  Where should I specify ordering for values in a drop-down list?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923799/reorder-users-in-django-auth

Comment: Found out that this question has already been discussed on StackOverFlow (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1474135/django-admin-ordering-of-foreignkey-and-manytomanyfield-relations-referencing-us), and also found the solution here: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6089#comment%3A8
Sorry for taking your time, guys, just after I raised a question correctly, I found out a solution in Google.

Answer (score 18):

You'd need to specify an override for the `team` field and then you should be able to override the order with its `queryset` argument. Here I'm assuming the property in `Team` you want to sort on is `name`.

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    team = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Team.objects.order_by('name'))

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('team',  'related_projects')
```

You can read more about ModelChoiceField here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield