# Sorting in django

Tags: python, django

Trying to sort a object inside another object.
I want to sort by A-name, that is showned in a dropdown.
Anyone that a have a idea?

```
Class A(models.model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

Class B(models.model):
    value = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    value2 = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

Class BForm(Forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        def myPage()
            myVar = BForm()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923799/reorder-users-in-django-auth and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997168/how-do-i-specify-an-order-of-values-in-drop-down-list-in-a-django-modelform

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just as simple as this:

```
aObjects = A.objects.order_by('name')[:30]
```

Comment: Thanks. always helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can set [`ordering`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#ordering) attribute of `Meta` class of `A`.

So you can define `A` as

```
Class A(models.model) :
    name = models.charfield(max.length=200);

    class Meta:
         ordering = ['name']
```

Comment: Perfect! I had look at that solution, but I thougt it would sort a list not a single object. Thanks again.