# Reorder FK fields in Django, remain optional

Tags: python, django

I have a model (Application) tied to a foreign_key (Person) table.  I was having trouble getting the Person-dropdown in the admin to sort by name instead of by key, and found this [Reorder users in django auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923799/reorder-users-in-django-auth) as a solution.   However, this made the fields mandatory and I can't figure out how to get them to stay optional.

app/models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):

       Full_Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
       def __unicode__(self):
                return self.Full_Name

class Application(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Primary_Contact = models.ForeignKey(Person,blank=True,null=True,related_name='appprimarycontact')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Name
```

admin.py

```
class OwnerAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Primary_Contact = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Person.objects.order_by('Full_Name'),)
    class Meta:
        model = Application

class ApplicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = OwnerAdminForm
    list_display = ('Name','Primary Contact')
```

Comment: `forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, ...)` ?

Comment: Oh for Pete's sake... I tried every possible placement of blank=True, null=True, etc, etc.  I feel dumb.  Make it an answer and I'll accept.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the `required=False` option on the form field

```
forms.ModelChoiceField(required=False, queryset=Person.objects.order_by('Full_Name'))
```

The thing is, if you override the default form widget that django's ModelForm would provide, you would have to explicitly specify `required=False`, since the default value is `True`